# Scala is adding (...) to .flatten and .max leading to a return of .flatten(...).max(...)

Tags: scala

I'm coming to Scala from Python/R (and some limited C# and Java) and am using Project Euler to practice my code writing. Basically, if I need to, I can write up a solution quickly in Python and then translate to Scala.

However, I'm stuck on the following:

*The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143*

The below code is attempting to apply Pollard's Rho algorithm to find the max factor. Unfortunately, every time I write factorList.max it automatically appends (...) to the end of max. I appreciate any feedback. And by all means tear my code up all you need. Always willing to learn!

```
def gcd(a: Long, b: Long): Long =
    if (b == 0) a else gcd(b, a % b)

  def compositeFinder(composite : Long , iterLimit : Int) : Int =
    {
/*      The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
      What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?*/

      var x = 2 : Long
      var y = 2 : Long
      var d = 1 : Long

      var factorList = ListBuffer()
      var iteration = 0
      while(iteration < iterLimit){
        x = (x*x + 1)%composite
        y = (y*y + 1)%composite
        d = gcd((x-y).abs,composite)

        if(d != 1 && d != composite && !factorList.contains(d)){
          factorList += d
        }
        iteration += 1
      }

      return factorList.flatten(...).max(...)
```

Comment: Idiomatic Scala doesn't use `var` or `return`. When you're ready for alternate solutions consult [this site](https://pavelfatin.com/scala-for-project-euler/).

Comment: This is great. Thank you for sharing!

Comment: Aside: make factorList a Set. Then there's no need for the contains test. Also, then don't test for 1 and composite either - let the loop complete, remove 1 and composite from the set, and carry on

Answer (score 2):

The IntelliJ editor will insert a `(...)` to indicate that the compiler can't find the "plumbing" (was implicits, now givens) needed to compile the specified method calls.

So what's wrong with your code?

First off, the compiler can't look ahead to see what type of elements the `ListBuffer()` *will* hold, so it's assigned a default element type, which is *not* what you want. This will fix it:

```
val factorList = ListBuffer[Long]()
```

Note: Prefer `val` over `var`.

Next, since `factorList` is a `ListBuffer` of `Long` elements, there's nothing to `flatten`. It's already flat.

```
factorList.max
```

Note: Don't use `return`. It does funny things. Just avoid it.

So this returns a `Long` but `compositeFinder()` is defined as returning an `Int`. Fix that and everything compiles.

But the bigger problem here is that you're writing C code in  the Scala language. Learning a new language is more than just learning the syntax. At its best, learning the idioms of a new language leads to learning new ways of thinking and problem solving.